# Using SVG Shadow Root with external source

Tags: html, svg

In our project we are calling all the icons like this:

```
<svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--extra-small  ">
<use xlink:href="#icon-search" href="#icon-search"></use>
</svg>
```

Right now we are loading all the icons in a hidden div at the footer of the document.

Is there a way to use an external source for the svg **without having to rewrite** all the icons?

Comment: If you mean all your Icons are external SVGs then use a ``<load-file>`` Web Component; which loads the SVG and adds it to the DOM. See: https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd

Answer (score 0):

I assume JavaScript is acceptable for your project. Here is an option that you could choose to do.
Create another file called svg-icons.js or anything really.
Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="svg-icons.js"></script>` below the closing `</body>` tag.

In that file, add something along the lines of:

```
document.querySelector('.my-icon').innerHTML = '<svg focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--extra-small  "><use xlink:href="#icon-search" href="#icon-search"></use></svg>';
```

Then whenever you want to use that icon in your html, add a div or span (according to your needs) with the same class: 
`<div class="my-icon"></div>`

The component is fairly small, so I don't suggest doing this. Additionally, if you are using JQuery, you could look into $.load(). That will help a lot when starting to use the same components across the entire website.